# Blender Crashing when changing from blender render to cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am having an issue with Blender whenever I change from blender render to cycles blender crashes or just shuts down.

if I go to the game engine no issue.

I am running a PC 
Windows 10
i5 CPU
GeForce GTX 1080 Ti

I am at a loss

Comment: Try the newest daily build

Comment: What is your Blender version?

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the error for me (taken from another thread): Turns out my WIndows Update was to blame, installing a .dll file that was breaking both Maya and Blender. This was called igdrclneo64.dll/igdrcl64.dll. It’s located in C:\Windows\System32 (On my computer it was located in C: \ Windows \ System32 \ DriverStore \ FileRepository \ igdlh64.inf_amd64_250db833a1cd577e.) I moved it to the desktop and now everything works